# Problema con ScheduledExecutorService al ejecutar en servicio android

Tags: java, android

Una pregunta, estoy creando un servicio en android, y necesito que este llame a un método cada cierto tiempo, y para ello estoy usando `ScheduledExecutorService`. Aquí les pongo el código:

```
@Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId){ //Método donde se ejecuta el código que tiene que hacer el servicio
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Servicio iniciado correctamente", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); //mostrar una notificación de servicio iniciado

      final Runnable ejecucion = new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Servicio(); //método que llamo cada 10 segundos
                }
            };
            ScheduledExecutorService timer = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
            timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(ejecucion, 10, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        return START_STICKY;
    }
```

El problema reside en que el método es llamado sólo una vez, cuando necesito que lo haga a intervalos que ya puse, investigando varias formas de hacerlo me topo con el mismo problema, lo que lleva a pensar que estoy omitiendo algo.

Comment: Juan, agrega tu método Servicio() y lo que despliega en el LogCat al detenerse, ahí debes tener el problema.

Answer (score 1):

El código que muestras para realizar una tarea cada x segundos mediante `ScheduledExecutorService`, te aseguro no tiene ningún problema, va a llamar cada 10 segundos el método `Servicio()`, el problema se encuentra dentro de este método.

```
 final Runnable ejecucion = new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Servicio(); //método que llamo cada 10 segundos
                }
            };
            ScheduledExecutorService timer = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
            timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(ejecucion, 10, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Agrega tu método `Servicio()` y lo que despliega en el LogCat al detenerse.